# How to use the new Spring Security AuthorizationManager?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Spring Security has replaced the two classes AccessDecisionManager and AccessDecisionVoter by the AuthorizationManager. Very nice. Unfortunately, the Spring Security team once again, as usual, did not think of providing newbies with useful examples. Why should they. It seems to be enough to say that it is done differently now. How exactly, is left to the newbie to find out in countless hours. The rabble has enough time anyway. And the pros know how it works for sure...

#### My goal is the following:

I want to implement an AuthorizationManager, which extends the current Spring Security decision logic with a custom voter. This voter shall decide as last instance with the help of ConfigAttributes, if an AccessDeniedException or an AuthorizationException is thrown (at least in legacy examples these exceptions were used to determine whether the authentication process is started or the AccessDeniedHandler is called).

To be a little more precise:

I want to annotate methods with the permission that calling these methods/endpoints will start the login process if the user is not logged in. Anything else will automatically result in a 404.

For the legacy classes there are enough examples to find on the internet. But for the new ones nothing - nothing at all :(. Can anyone please tell me where I can find examples for the **implementation of a custom AuthorizationManager that takes the existing voter into account and implements my own voter** as well?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: They've written a [migration guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#_replace_any_custom_filter_security_accessdecisionmanagers). Not sure whether there is actually anything useful for you.

Comment: @AlexR: thanks for the link. I have now spent more than two hours trying to get this thing running with this well-hidden migration guide - but I can't even get proper method-securiting with it. All to read are code snippets without a complete executable example. always just a few fragments of this and a few tips of that. It would be really nice to see an actual executable example on the topic of Method-Security with custom decision management. That should be daily bread imo.

Comment: The intended changes are so immense that a migration seems to be a real challenge. I expect executable code examples from a professional framework development team. I'm not stupid, but I can't even manage proper security with the new @EnableMethodSecurity and authorizeHttpRequests. Shame on me or shame on Spring Security?

Comment: I'm just down this rabbithole as well. And when there are a couple of code examples lines, the classes in the libraries don't have the methods shown in the sample code.

Comment: Exactly I have the same issue , did you find any solution please !!!!

Comment: If you want to be able to send them to the login page you don't need custom voters or managers. Just a regular `@PreAuthorize("#authentication.authenticated")` is needed for that.

Comment: Yes, that's the default behavior of Spring Security. But I want this behavior only for dedicated annotated methods, and anything else should end in showing a 404 page.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a few months old, but I haven't seen the answer elsewhere, so I'm going to share what I've found:

As I read the new docs, it looks like you chain `access(AuthorizationManager<T> authorizationManager)` into your `requestMatchers()` call for the URL pattern. `AuthorizationManager<T>` is an interface with two methods:

```
default void verify(Supplier<Authentication> authentication, T object)
```

Determines if access should be granted for a specific `authentication` and `object`.
Parameters:
`authentication` - the `Supplier` of the `Authentication` to check
`object` - the `AuthorizationManager` object to check
Throws:
`AccessDeniedException` - if access is not granted

```
@Nullable
AuthorizationDecision check(Supplier<Authentication> authentication, T object)
```

Determines if access is granted for a specific `authentication` and `object`.
Parameters:
`authentication` - the `Supplier` of the `Authentication` to check
`object` - the `AuthorizationManager` object to check

Returns:
an `AuthorizationDecision` or null if no decision could be made

Extend AuthorizationManager with your logic in the `access(...)` and `verify(...)` methods, chain it to your `RequestMatcher` logic, and that looks like it.

To understand how this fits in to the current architecture look here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html#request-authorization-architecture

As a quick summary, the default last step in the `SecurityFilterChain` is the `AuthorizationFilter`, which gets the current Authentication from the `SecurityContext` and passes it to an `AuthorizationManager`. The authorization manager can perform whatever logic you want to make the authorization decision, then pass it back to the AuthorizationFilter.

**Edit to add**
Looking again,the base interface is `AuthorizationManager<T>` but the constructor for `AuthorizationFilter` expects to receive an `AuthorizationManager<HttpServletRequest>`. Your code might compile initially, but you'll probably get an exception when `AuthorizationManager` calls one of the methods with the wrong type for `T object`.