# How to migrate this AccessDecisionManager to AuthorizationManager for OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I need to migrate my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class to SecurityFilterChain bean base configuration
in here I am able to migrate all other thing except **AccessDecisionManager**.

I checked the many links but did not find find the correct way(chatGpt too, in this case chatGpt is useless since it has only knowledge till sep 2021 and these classes/interfaces were deprecated recently), I am kinda stuck here ,Need help here.
I already went through spring doc [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#_replace_any_custom_filter_security_accessdecisionmanagers)
and this article on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75035929/how-to-use-the-new-spring-security-authorizationmanager)
I am not able to understand how can I do it .
I tried change WebExpressionVoter  ->WebExpressionAuthorizationManager but in this setExpressionHandler expect SecurityExpressionHandler RequestAuthorizationContext but OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler implements SecurityExpressionHandler FilterInvocation.
I took udemy courses too but it didn't help aslo, I guess only a spring security expert can help me here.

```
@Bean
public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager(final ApplicationContext context) {
    // Le sigh java generics
    WebExpressionVoter webExpressionVoter = new WebExpressionVoter();
    OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setApplicationContext(context);
    webExpressionVoter.setExpressionHandler(expressionHandler);
    List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters = Arrays.asList(webExpressionVoter);
    return new UnanimousBased(decisionVoters);
}
```

Any lead/pointers would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!